# Unable to connect to iOs simulator using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, debugging, xamarin

Im having a problem when debugging my Xamarin.Forms app using the iOs Simulator on my Windows 10 laptop...

On my windows machine I am running VS2017 latest version, on the mac I am running Visual Studio Community 2017 and installed the Alpha updates.

Then I downgraded the Xamarin.iOs to stable version (only downgraded xamarin.ios) to fix some compile errors...

In the end it compiles > It starts the simulator > It displays: "Updating(0%)"..

This is where I am stuck.. hope anyone knows a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use the iOS simulator on your Windows laptop? 
if so, the iOS simulator requires VS/msdn Enterprise subscription.

Either way double check that the iOS version matches on your simulator and iOS project build settings,make sure your macOS and xcode is updated.

I've had problems in the past with debugging on my macbook/simulator from windows/vs, and updating the macbook/xcode usually works.

Also, try having the simulator already open before debugging.